# AVPlayer Questions, while Live Streaming (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, volume, avplayer

I have AVPlayer Questions.

1.How to control the volume of it?

2.How to know if the AVPlayer is reloading music because bad connection, do i have some inidication of it?

Comment: can you tell me how did you stream music using AVPlayer??

Comment: Using apple http live streaming guides on the server.

Answer (score 7):

`AVPlayer` uses the system volume, so if you need to provide controls for this you can use `MPVolumeView` which gives you the slider for volume control.

For audio fading, you can use an `AVAudioMix`.  Here's some code:

```
//given an AVAsset called asset...
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
id audioMix = [[AVAudioMix alloc] init];
id volumeMixInput = [[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters alloc] init];

//fade volume from muted to full over a period of 3 seconds
[volumeMixInput setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0 toEndVolume:1 timeRange:
     CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(3, 1))];
[volumeMixnput setTrackID:[[asset tracks:objectAtIndex:0] trackID]];

[audioMix setInputParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:volumeMixInput]];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];
```

You can also abruptly set the volume for a mix at a given time with:

```
[volumeMixInput setVolume:.5 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(15, 1)];
```

Hope this helps.  This API is definitely not obvious.  I'd highly recommend watching the WWDC 10 video entitled *Discovering AV Foundation*.  It's excellent.

Comment: just realized this only answers your volume question.  Might be best to post that separately.

Comment: Note that, per Apple, this method only works for _file_-based assets.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1716/_index.html