# Muting an AVPlayer playing Http Live Streaming video

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avaudiosession

I was wondering if I could mute the **sound** of an **AVPlayer** playing a **HTTP Live Streaming video**?

I've already try several things, like the Apple method to set the volume of an **AVPlayer** [explained here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1716/_index.html) but it works only for local files... (cf. the note at the bottom of Apple documentation).

The similar method explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237070/avplayer-questions-while-live-streaming-ios) does not working either.

Is there an solution? I really don't want to mute the sound of the device but only one video while other players could have their own audio (the user could balance audio between players).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AVFoundation team, it is impossible to mute or disable a track of an HLS video.

Comment: Indeed, I've seen it a while ago… But I was looking for a possible hack or something else. I change the behavior of the app, that was my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

iOS 7.0 now provides support for muting the player using

```
[AVPlayer setVolume:(float)volume]
```

It also works for HTTP Live Streaming, my app is making extensive use of it.

Comment: Indeed I saw that earlier. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mute the entire audio session using MPMusicPlayerController shared instance.

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer ]setVolume:0];
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't looking for that : "I really don't want to mute the sound of the device but only one video while other players could have their own audio (the user could balance audio between players)."